# Set codepage of forms in a setup and deployment project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I have a setup and deployment project (VS 2010) and I added TextBox Form in the UI view. The text I want to show to the user is not English, it's Greek. When I run the msi, the text looks more like an ancient dwarven language.

Now, I don't want to localize the whole msi (i don't want alternative texts for different languages and all this stuff). I just want this particular text to show properly. Is there a way to set the code-page the msi will use?

Comment: @HansPassant That is not completely true: although the Windows Installer engine uses Unicode internally, the database, i.e. msi file, is not Unicode-based. Each MSI file always target a particular code page. It would have been much more easier if it was fully Unicode-base. I guess the decision to use code pages was made because they wanted to support Windows 9x.

Answer (score 1):

Usually MSI has code page set to [1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) for English.

For displaying Greek characters, the code page must be set to [1253](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1253). \
English text will be still displayed correctly.

You need to set the correct LangId for your Product, and set the code page in the Summary Tabel. For more information see [Code Page Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367867%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
I cannot provide guiding as to where this is set in the Visual Studio deployment project.